# Drools / Java 8 compatibility

Tags: drools, compatibility

I am trying to use Drools for rules validation, and I get an error with Java 8. As per the existing suggestions, I did upgrade to eclipse compiler to 4.4 and see the corresponding ecj-4.4.jar generated in my maven dependencies. However, I am still getting the wrong class format exception:

Caused by: org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException.

I tried using different versions of drools including 6.4.0.Final, 5.0.1 as well - but the issue persists.

I get this error when I try using the Stateless kie session but not with the stateful kie session.

Any thoughts?

Best Regards,
Sadhana

Comment: Could you please add the code you are using and the exception you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using drools compiler dependency then change it below in `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
    <version>${drools.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
               <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

If you are using drools-spring dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
    <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${drools-spring-version}</version>
     <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
               <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The error you are facing could be because there are multiple version of ecj jar and Java is picking the wrong one.